# How to avoid using the expect_any_instance_of hammer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I've got a few tests like this:

```
it 'should invite user again' do
    admin_user = create(:invited_admin_user)
    expect_any_instance_of(AdminUser).to receive(:invite!).and_return(true)
    patch :reinvite, params: { id: admin_user.to_param }
end
```

I really want to write it like this:

```
it 'should invite user again' do
    admin_user = create(:invited_admin_user)
    expect(admin_user).to receive(:invite!).and_return(true)
    patch :reinvite, params: { id: admin_user.to_param }
end
```

But the test fails if I do that. Any idea why that would happen? I'm using factory_bot to create the AdminUser instance.

I've tried putting puts statements in the test and the invite method to confirm the ID.

```
def invite!(_param1 = AdminUser.new, _param2 = {})
    puts 'ID in invite!' + self.id.inspect
    super(_param1, _param2)
end

it 'should invite user again' do
    admin_user = create(:invited_admin_user)
    puts 'adminuser created' + admin_user.id.inspect
    expect(admin_user).to receive(:invite!).and_return(true)
    patch :reinvite, params: { id: admin_user.to_param }
end
```

Result

> adminuser created7768
>
> ID in invite!7768

Comment: can you please add reinvite action as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to use mocks here in the first place?

```
it 'should invite user again' do
  admin_user = create(:invited_admin_user)
  patch :reinvite, params: { id: admin_user.to_param }
  expect(admin_user.reload.invited).to eq(true)
end
```

If you want to avoid redundant calls to the database, the whole test should be written a) without a real DB object creation (`FactoryGirl#build`,) b) without `patch` call (directly call the respective controller’s method,) and c) mocking everything to be called in between.

**NB** I personally do not see any reason at all to have tests where everything is mocked: they hardly differ from the code itself. I mean, we could make a mistake in the test as well as in the code and checking that `patch` calls the respective controller’s method is silly: it’s already checked in Rails tests. I always try to test *real* things, when applicable (like the user was indeed changed, rather than some method was invoked.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your code is finding the record afresh and instantiating it as a new object, therefore the object that receives the message is different to the one in your test.

To get round this do:

```
it 'should invite user again' do
  admin_user = create(:invited_admin_user)
  expect(User).to receive(:find).with(admin_user.id).and_return(admin_user)
  expect(admin_user).to receive(:invite!).and_return(true)
  patch :reinvite, params: { id: admin_user.to_param }
end
```

This just intercepts the User.find call and returns your test object rather than the one it would normally initialise.

Comment: Hmm interesting. My code doesn't actually use find:
      @admin_users = AdminUser.deleted.where(email: admin_user_params[:email])

(and then it iterates over each one). It seems a bit hacky to have to override .find anyway. Is this a recommended practice or am I just trying to do the wrong thing?

Comment: It’s not ideal to put an expectation on `find` but if you don’t want to use expect_any_instance_of there’s very little choice. There’s an argument that your function calling `invite!` is an implementation detail and instead you could check the end result such as an email being triggered or an `invite_sent_at` timestamp being updated if those are things which happen. That said, your question was quite specific so I gave the answer to that. Do any of these alternatives help you?